# Getting shape not aligned error sklearn .

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression, sklearn-pandas

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
Dataset = pd.read_csv('Salary_Data.csv')
Salary , YearsExperience = Dataset['Salary'] ,Dataset['YearsExperience'] 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(YearsExperience , 
Salary, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
Regressor = LinearRegression()
Regressor.fit(X_train.values.reshape(1,-1),y_train.values.reshape(1,-1))    
y_pred = Regressor.predict(X_test.values.reshape(1,-1))
```

So I've written this code do do a linear regression . But I get an error on the .predict line where the error says

```
ValueError: shapes (1,10) and (20,20) not aligned: 10 (dim 1) != 20 (dim 0)
```

but when I keep the test_size as 0.5 the error does not occur . Can you explain why this happens ? What do I do ?

Comment: Add the shapes of the variables i.e. Dataset.shape, X_train.shape etc to your question

Answer (score 1):

If you don't reshape your data at all sklearn gives you a hint:

```
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

As your data has a single feature, you have to reshape it to (-1, 1) instead of (1, -1)